# Why question do not have duplicate question link?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else) question is closed as exact duplicate by [Charlie Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35092/charlie-martin). Then why doesn't it have a "Possible Duplicate" block on the top of question? Also Charlie is not a moderator then how come he had alone closed this question?

Comment: Not really relevant, but Charlie's profile is great: "God I've been doing this a long time -- since 1969. And the temptation to answer some teenage hacker with 'you'll understand when you grow up' gets stronger and stronger. In the mean time, stay the hell offa my lawn."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was closed before the current rules (5 votes and duplicate added) were implemented.

Comment: so the rules are not from the beginning.

Comment: @Harry - no - all the rules on the site have evolved over time based on experience of using them and how they break as the site grows.

Comment: Okay...

Comment: @HarryJoy: StackOverflow's old west was ought nine.